# Spring webflux Multiple Exception handler in functional Endpoint

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

im working ins Spring web flux project and I used functional endpoints instead of controller annotation but I didn't find a solution to handle multiple exceptions for the same endpoint , this is my code :

```
@Override
protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRoutingFunction(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes) {
    return RouterFunctions.route(RequestPredicates.GET("/router/users/{id}"),this::renderException);
}

private Mono<ServerResponse> renderException(ServerRequest request) {

    Map<String, Object> error = this.getErrorAttributes(request, ErrorAttributeOptions.defaults());
    error.remove("status");
    error.remove("requestId");
    return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromValue(error));
}
```

for the endpoint `/router/users/{id}` i trigger UserNotFoundException and UserException and I want to return 404 for UserNotFoundException and 500 for UserException  but I don't know how to do that in the functional endpoint. anyone can guide me on how to do this in the correct way like we did in using @ExceptionHandler in rest controller?

Answer (score 0):

If returning proper code is all you care about then adding `@ResponseStatus` for your custom exceptions might be the best solution.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class UserNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {

    // more methods...
    
    public UserNotFoundException(final String message) {
        super(message);
    }

}
```

But if you want to build `ServerResponse` by yourself, make use of project reactor operators, like `switchIfEmpty()` or `onErrorMap()`, etc. which could be used as following

```
Mono<ServerResponse> response() {
    return exampleService.getUser()
        .flatMap(user -> ServerResponse.ok().body(user, User.class))
        .switchIfEmpty(ServerResponse.notFound().build());
}
```

You might want to take a look at docs [Which operator do I need? - handling errors](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#which.errors)

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i will roolback my code and go back to traditional RestController it's very easy... unfortunately functional endpoint it's not a mature solution , a lot of things are missing especially excepion handling unit test....